# How does Google Play Service install applications on the background without user interaction

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

When we use the Google Play Store to install applications, the application will be installed automatically without any Package Installer notification. It does not even require any user interaction when updating applications. It won't do so when we use the F-Droid or others.

We developers can bypass the Package Installer via running `pm install some.apk` as `shell` or `root`, but personally it seems to be more elegant to achieve this task by calling some Java methods, and Play Store itself may just be running as a normal app or at most `system`.

Therefore I would like to know how this is done. It would be much more better if codes from https://android.googlesource.com/ can be provided as evidences. Thank you.

Comment: Well this is impossible, without root privileges you are not supposed to install an app without user's explicit permission, otherwise there would have been too many viruses for Android

Comment: @Chaosit It might be true, but Play Store might not well be running as the dangerous `root`, is it? It can literally install apps without our explicit permission. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only system apps can install packages without interaction. System apps have root-like access rights. Google play is the system application, and is able to install packages in background without confirmation. that's the only reason.

Comment: Got it. It's mentioned in the hidden `android.content.pm.PackageManager#installPackage` method. Thank you.